# Designing my models for binding to DataGrid items and headers

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I'm trying to obtain a DataGrid in my View from some DATA in my Model. I think i must reorganize the DATA in my ViewModel to display them in my View.
I'm new in MVVM and I'd like to understand 2 points of the question:

1. Taking in mind that I do not know neither the number of the rows, neither the number of the columns, what kind of data holder i should use? ObservableCollection<>?
   More in detail each row will have an item, and each column will have an aspect of the item.
2. How can I set the Headers of my DataGrid?

The rows should apperar like 1,2,3...
The columns should have their specific names.

This is my try:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="false" ItemsSource="{Binding MyTable}" />
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs:

```
private ObservableCollection<List<MyItem>> _myTable;
public class MyItem
{
    public MyItem(string value)
    {
        Value= value;
    }
    public string Value{ get; set; }
}
public ObservableCollection<List<MyItem>> MyTable
{
    get
    {
        return _myTable;
    }

    set
    {
        _myTable = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("MyTable");
    }
}
```

The execute of the comand is:

```
private void DisplayDataTableExecute()
    {
        MyTable = new ObservableCollection<List<MyItem>>();
        var temp = new List<MyItem>();
        temp.Add(new MyItem("one"));
        temp.Add(new MyItem("two"));
        temp.Add(new MyItem("three"));
        MyTable.Add(temp);
        temp = new List<MyItem>();
        temp.Add(new MyItem("ONE"));
        temp.Add(new MyItem("TWO"));
        temp.Add(new MyItem("THREE"));
        MyTable.Add(temp);
    }
```

When i use the AutoGenerateColumns="false" I only see some rows (the correct number but empty) when i use the AutoGenerateColumns="true" i see the properties of the table (Capacity and Count).

I really need some help, because i can't find a solution.

Comment: `ObservableCollection<MyItem>` is a monodimensional array, i need a bidimensional array, my original data are a `String[][]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main issues here:

First: You can't use `AutoGenerateColumns = "false"` without setting up columns. You'll need to map these through yourself, ie:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="false" ItemsSource="{Binding MyTable}" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value"  Binding="{Binding Value}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Note that you can just set `AutoGenerateColumns="true"` instead, which will give you one column per property in your class.

Second: You will need to make your class (`class MyItem`) implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` if you want to have changes made in code reflected in the UI.

Comment: Third: the ObservableCollection is of type List<MyType>, hence each row is expecting to display a List<MyType> and not a MyType. That's going to be fun! Since the rest of your answer is good, @Reed, I'll leave you to expand on that if you feel like it!

Comment: When i set `AutoGenerateColumns = "true"`, i do not see my values but i can only see the properties of the data (Es. the lenght of the strings). For the columns i can't map them because their number changes, and i know it only runtime.

Comment: @simonatrcl Good point - missed that one - that's going to be nasty

Comment: @IllidanMalar You can setup columns in code, too - see DataGrid.Columns for an example.

Comment: @Reed: I've followed your idea, i've created a `delegate` in code behind that ask to my ViewModel to create the `List<DataGridTextColumn>` and add the columns to the `DataGrid`. This `delegate` is called by ViewModel each time a `RaisePropertyChanged("MyTable")` is called. Everything is working fine BUT... ...i'm breaking the MVVM paradigm?

Comment: @IllidanMalar Yes, somewhat - you could always do this as an attached property or behavior in the View, though, so it wouldn't be in the VM...